# node-migrate: can I use es6 import in migration script?

Tags: node.js, migration, database-migration

With node-migration npm package can I use es6 imports

I want to do:

```
import dash from './utils/rethinkdb';

let r = dash();
exports.up = function(next){
  next();
};

exports.down = function(next){
  next();
};
```

I know that i can just require, but I am writing everything in es6 so, wanted to be consistent

Thx

Answer (score 0):

It does not necessarily depend on the migration framework you use, but on node.js itself.

Node.js has a "bit" of support for ES6 already, by using the `--harmony` flag. Take a look at it, if all your features you want are covered by `--harmony`, this might be an option:

https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/es6-%28a.k.a.-harmony%29-features-implemented-in-v8-and-available-in-node

Another option is to use https://babeljs.io/ to transpile your code back to ES5 in order to run it.

Also note, if you're using io.js, you have to know that io.js doesn't handle the `--harmony` flag exactly the same as node does. All you need to know about this, you can read here:

https://iojs.org/en/es6.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However node-migrate has its own cli and 'migrate --harmony' and '--compilers js:babel/register' does not work, as --harmony and --compilers are not recongnized by migrate. I can traspile the project to es5 js and then execute a script, but its not ideal

Comment: it is still node, no matter if it has its own cli or not, this cli doesn't run without node. just edit the shell script (find it with which applicationname) of your installed framework, e.g. #!/bin/node to #!/bin/node --harmony or something like this

Comment: And if this does not help, maybe you also can open an issue in the project of github and asking for this feature or if there is a way to accomplish this.